# Unity C# float value not decreasing on "OnCollisionEnter2d"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First have a look at my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Layer : MonoBehaviour {

    public float health=150f;
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D beam){
        if (beam.gameObject.tag == "Box") {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }

        Projectile enemyship = beam.gameObject.GetComponent<Projectile> ();   // Retrieving enemyship
        if (enemyship) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
            health = health - 100f; // its value is decreasing only once
            Debug.Log (health);
            if (health < 0f || health == 0f) {
                Destroy (enemyship.gameObject); // this line not executing
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In my above code the value of health is decreasing only once but OnCollisionEnter2D is working properly. That means on first collision the health value decreases by 100f and it becomes 50f but when it collides second time it's value is still 50f. And I have been looking since 3 hour for this solution. Please help me

I am adding little more thing. I am firing a projectile(laser) when I pressed space. So when laser hits twice object was supposed to be destroyed

Comment: `if (enemyship) { Destroy (gameObject);` you're destroying object with that health so it wont hit again...

Comment: *OnCollisionEnter2D is working properly" - did you actually confirm this using breakpoints? It sounds like the event handler is only firing once.

Comment: You should also write `if (health < 0f || health == 0f)` as `if (health <= 0)`

Comment: @DavidG I have tried that

Comment: I'm not saying that it fixes your problem, just that it's more readable.

Comment: @CoolBots yup Debug.log is showing the result everytime laser collides but health value is only 50f. No matter how many times it collides

Comment: @DavidG I mean to say earlier I have written that but as it was not working. I thought that will work

Comment: I think your `Layer` object may be getting discarded and re-created - in which case, the health value is reset to 150 on every collision. Can you make `health` a static field and see if it decreases? If it does, you need to figure out why your object is being destroyed and re-created. See the first comment on your post - that would likely be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so first thing you're doing wrong is that your collision logic makes no sense at all. Your colliding object is *"let's say a mortal object"* which has to *"die"* whenever it's health is lower or equal to `0` but you're destroying it every time it collides with anything that has tag `Box` or has component of type `Projectile`.
To fix this first reduce the health based on these condition and then check if you want to destroy that object or not.

*example code:*

```
public float health = 150f;

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D beam)
{
    float damage = 0f; // current damage...
    if (beam.gameObject.tag == "Box") 
    {
        // Destroy (gameObject); // do not destroy, just remove health
        damage = health; // reduce health to 0
    }
    else
    {
        Projectile enemyship = beam.gameObject.GetComponent<Projectile> ();   
        if (enemyship) 
        {
            // Destroy (gameObject); // again do not destroy.. just reduce health
            damage = 100f;
        }
    }

    health -= damage;
    Debug.Log (health); // print your health

    // check if dead
    if (health < 0f || health == 0f) {
        Destroy (gameObject); // this line not executing
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I have solve it myself. But thanks. My logic makes sense but I have to decrease the health of another object not of mine.

Comment: not health = health - 100f but enemyship.health -= 100f. health was of object with which this script is attached too and since it is getting destroyed it was again being reset. Thanks for helping me